How to add custom field to Drupal 10 Ckeditor5 core plugin in the TableProperties popup
How to add custom text field to Drupal 10 Ckeditor5 core plugin in the TableProperties popup here:
enter image description here
I am using this patch to enable TableCellProperties and TableProperties => https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3324225
Usually I am importing this way: import { Plugin } from 'ckeditor5/src/core'; but TableProperties is not part of the ckeditor5/src/core
